# How to correctly access and have google maps/earth display a KML file with public acl from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-cloud-storage

I can successfully create and displayed google maps uri from a KML/KMZ file created and stored in Google Drive with no issues via the MyMaps option.  I would like to do the same with Google Cloud Storage, so that I don't have to use my Google Drive. Each time I've tested, I have created a new file name, incase Google Maps servers are caching the KML/KMZ file.

**My goal:** *use a Google Cloud Storage KML file and a uri/UL to access the map I've created into the KML file.*

I've tried many variations on the following uri to access the kml file via google maps and earth, firstly from Google Chrome:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=https://storage.googleapis.com/mapper/testkml1.kmz
```

I just get the error back

We could not find https://storage.googleapis.com/mapper/testkml1.kmz

Here's an image of the original map that I exported the KML from.

[image: MyMap from which I exported the KML file]

and here's the result I get - Maps is not finding the the kml file.  (Please note there will be variations in the file names, I changed them each time.)

[image]

I thought Google Cloud Storage was supposed to be a production like version of Google Drive personal storage, kinda.  Granted Google currently has a hook into Google Drive and MyMaps.

Here's what I've done to create the KML/KMZ file

I've created a Cloud Storage file [testkml1.kmz](https://console.developers.google.com/m/cloudstorage/b/mapper/o/testkml1.kmz?authuser=0) and given it public access and read capability to all but the owner via Google Maps, MyMap, Create .  It contains the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
<Document>
    <name>TestKML</name>
    <description><![CDATA[Testing KML]]></description>
    <Folder>
        <name>KMLLayer</name>
    </Folder>
    <Folder>
        <name>Untitled layer</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Point 1</name>
            <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-77.0699501,38.9027896,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Pentagon</name>
            <description><![CDATA[What's the four wall profitability?]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-77.0704651,38.8720575,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Style id='icon-503-DB4436'>
        <IconStyle>
            <color>ff3644DB</color>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
            </hotSpot>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Do one thing, from google storage send an embed link or just do share via email (there should be an option). Send it to one of your other emails. You will get an URL. Use that one instead.

Comment: Might have tried this, but I'll give it another shot. I've used the link from the bucket option drop down.